# Mysterious Non-Error Errors across a Parent 4.0/Child 2.0 asp net site

Tags: asp.net, web-config, assemblies

I have a web site that I maintain for a veteran's organization. It is composed of several asp net applications, most of which are .net 4.0. The one exception is Screwturn wiki, which is running under 2.0. In order to make screwturn run, I had to add this to my web config:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false" allowOverride="false">
```

This allowed Screwturn to run, but introduced a number of non-error errors into my web site. By this I mean, they show up as errors when I compile, but not when I actually run the site. Everything on the site, as best I can tell, runs without any issues.

All of the components generating errors exist in a directory called "Components" which is shared between the main website and screwturn wiki. They are used to make both websites look like a single application. For example, on the left side of the site is a flyout menu that appears both on the main site and screwturn. For this reason, I'm guessing that these non-error errors have something to do with 2.0 vs. 4.0.

The errors I'm getting look something like this:

```
Error   123 <<Website>>\Components\Database\HistorySearch.ascx.cs(1): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HistoryService' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)        
Error   122 <<Website>>\Components\Menu\Admin.ascx.cs(1): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'bg401st' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)       
Error   124 <<Website>>\Components\Photo\MemberImagePrimary.ascx.cs(3): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)       
Error   132 The type or namespace name 'Aircraft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  <<WebSite>>\Components\Database\HistorySearch.ascx.cs   34  
Error   149 The type or namespace name 'HostManagerSoapClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) <<WebSite>>\Components\Photo\AvailableImages.ascx.cs    11  
Error   127 The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) <<WebSite>>\Components\Database\HistorySearch.ascx.cs   5
```

All of which make me think of this section within the  tag:

```
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
      ...
```

So, is there a way to fix these "errors?" Does it involve placing something in the assemblies section, above? Or a setting somewhere else?

Like I said, my site still runs, so it's not a huge issue. I'd just like to have my site show no errors when I compile and am ready to publish.

EDIT:

The assemblies in question are being reference by using statements in the code. I, in fact, went so far as to explicitly create namespaces for some of the code that did not previously have them so I could reference them as a using in order to get rid of those errors. Didn't work.

Comment: In the usings statements in MemberImagePrimary.ascx.cs, is it using System.Linq?

Comment: Yes, there are using statements in all of the files that are getting these errors, so that's not my problem. I'll edit my question accordingly. On the other hand, Linq did not exist for asp 2.0, which is why I think this has to do with the <location> tag. Although, to be clear, I'm actually running Screwturn under 3.5...

Comment: Yes, that's where I was going with the question. Your source has System.Linq, but your assemblies section in the config calls in System.Xml.Linq and System.Data.Linq.

Check to make sure your references node doesn't have any of those warning icons on the referenced assemblies as well. Those components are likely somewhere or, if they are just DLL's in the bin folder, you could see it run, but be getting these errors in VS. Add them as references if they aren't added.

Comment: Well, that is something to take a closer look at. Thanks. I don't believe I need to be using those other two, but...le'me try tweaking...

Comment: Following up: System.Linq, unless I'm misunderstanding something, is in System.Core which is referenced in my assemblies, so... not sure that's the problem. Also, not all of the errors I'm getting are Linq related. The error concerning Aircraft is an application object, for example.